# Unity 3D 2D Imported Sprites Pixelated

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, powerpoint, sprite, pixel

I have this image generated thanks to PowerPoint:

[image: Sprite Home]

We can see here, the image is not pixelated.

But when I import this in Unity 3D, the result is:

[image: Result in Unity 3D]

Here you can see the sprite's parameters:

[image: Sprite's parameter]

1. Am I using the correct tool for my sprite creation? (PowerPoint)
2. If the answer is "No", which tool can I use for avoid this kind of problem?
3. If the answer is "Yes", how can I avoid this pixelization of my sprite in Unity 3D?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint is not the best image editor :D But your sprite looks correct, possible you just set small scale in Unity Scene window for it.

Try increasing your sprite Scale in Scene window. Select it, next in Inspector increase X Y Z Scale parameters in Transform component (it should be on top).

Comment: My sprite was very huge, and when i'm decreasing the size, it gets pixelated :(
Should I re-do it more smaller?
Which image editor are you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your image in my Unity editor and it seems fine. Make sure your Sprite Renderer transform scale is set to (1,1,1). For me even that seems not to affect the quality but it is a best practice not to have different distorted scales for everything in your scene.

One tip for improving your sprite quality is to export it in a POT resolution. Meaning that the resolution of the image should be divisible with 4. This way Unity will be able to compress the image with a much higher precision and quality. One resolution example of that is 800x800 or 1920x1080 etc.

Make sure your build target is set to Standalone and not other platform. If you are set to Android for example. check the Android specific compression in your sprite import inspector. That might also affect the quality.

To answer your question on what image editor to use, the best one, in my opinion, is Adobe Photoshop. If you don't want to pay for it, just search for any free image editing tool. But stop using PP, I'm not exactly sure how you have come up with that.